# WPF Grid - Dynamic Data

Tags: wpf

I have searched everywhere and cannot find an answer to this!
Using a WPF Grid bound to a SQL Server, how do you have the Grid load/refresh with a parameter for the SQL Query?
I need to type a value into a text box, press a button and have the grid return all rows that match the value in the text box.

In the web world this is simple. (Select * from TABLE where col = @param )
@param = a control on the page and all of this is under a Sub.

Using VB but can also read c#.

Comment: Just an FYI, every MSDN and "tip" shows me how to query a table but not set a parameter to filter query when it executed before the results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

What is your snag exactly? I implemented this in C#, focusing on this part of your question: "I need to type a value into a text box, press a button and have the grid return all rows that match the value in the text box."

```
public void RefreshDB()
{
    lbAreas.ItemsSource = null;
    lbNumbers.ItemsSource = null;
    listNumbers = new List<string>();
    listAreas = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        string strCommand = "SELECT * FROM Phonebook";
        if (myTextBox.Text != "")
        {
            strCommand += " WHERE Area=\'" + myTextBox.Text + "\'";
        }
        using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strCommand,connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listNumbers.Add(reader["Number"].ToString());
                    listAreas.Add(reader["Area"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    lbAreas.ItemsSource = listAreas;
    lbNumbers.ItemsSource = listNumbers;
}
```

And then I have a Button which I click to do the filtering.

```
private void Filter_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RefreshDB();
}
```